# Finding if two arrays have common numbers using recursion

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

The question goes like this: 
write a recursive function that gets two positive int arrays and their sizes.
The function returns 0 if there is at least one common object and 1 if there isn't.

```
int disjoint(int a[], int n1, int b[], int n2)
```

The requirements are as follows:

- no helper functions
- no loops
- no changing the array
- only recursion

I am currently having problems in getting all the combinations for comparison, in other words how to translate nested loops to recursion.

***update***
this one works but it makes unnecessary iterations.

```
int disjoint(int g1[], int n1 , int g2[], int n2 ){
if(g1[0]==g2[0])return 0;
if(n2-1>0&&n1-1>=0){
return disjoint(g1+1,n1-1,g2,n2)*disjoint(g1,n1,g2+1,n2-1);
}
return 1;
}
```

Comment: @PaulR  just added, thanks

Comment: Posting the code in which "currently having problems in getting all the combinations for comparison ..." would help clarify your goal/issue.

Comment: It would make more sense if the signature was `int disjoint(const int a[],  int n1, const int b[], int n2)` and then drop "no changing the array".

Comment: How exactly is a number "similar" to another one? Do you mean "equal"? Or is "11" *similar* to "111"

Comment: @chux thanks but the signature is as I wrote it.

Comment: @tofro in similar I mean equal.

Comment: About your update: explain (show).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not solving it for you but...

Using pseudo-annotation: The arrays `a[0..n]` and `b[0..m]` are disjoint if `a[0] != b[0]` and if `a[1..n]` and `b[0..m]` are disjoint *and* `a[0..n]` and `b[1..m]` are disjoint.

I *think* I got that right...

Ok, another hint: One of the recursive calls might look like `disjoint(a + 1, n1 - 1, b, n2)`

When doing recursion, it's (at least for me) better to look at the problem and formulate the solution in terms of the problem itself, rather than writing an iterative solution and then trying to "translate" it.

Comment: Positively agree to your last statement - Starting from scratch when doing recursion is way easier than trying to refactor an iterative solution.